# Ways to create animations in python?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, tkinter, ffmpeg

What is the best way to create a small animation in python?
So far, I have tried: tkinter and FuncAnimation (from animation in matplotlib- this is what is used in A Student's Guide to Python for Physical Modeling).

The goal is to make a set of simple animations, but FuncAnimation is having me install apt-get so that I can get ffmpeg so I can run the animation. It seems like a lot of downloading, which I don't prefer if there is a similarly powerful alternative.

If possible, I was hoping to integrate these animations into Pygame at a later time. Will that be possible?

YES, this is a subjective question, but I am looking for guidance from experienced python animators. What are the objective strengths and weaknesses of different methods of animating in Python?

Comment: When asking a question like "What are methods..." or "Which alternative can I use for.." you need to be really specific about the criteria. Otherwise the question would be off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 2):

*Note that the following is rather a long comment than an answer as the question as it stands is hardly answerable at all. I will probably delete it after it has been read by the questioner.*

Using `FuncAnimation` or `ArtistAnimation` is the most common and recommended way for animations in matplotlib.
You can show the animation on screen or save it, e.g. as an animated gif, an mp4 video or a bunch of single frames.

There is no interface to pygame. But of course you can use the saved pictures in pygame.

Other methods of animation would require a redraw of the canvas on command. Those are well suited for on-screen animation, but need more hands-on for saving. None of them would be considered supperior to FuncAnimation.